# How to get whole string before last underscore( _ ) character in php?

Tags: php

i have get whole string before last underscore character in php
example : `$string = "Test_Download_24_12_2019_16:38.pdf";`
and expected output below

> Test_Download_24_12_2019

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: First, explode the string: `$exploded = explode('_', $string);` Then, remove the last array element: `array_pop($exploded);`. Then, implode the string back together: `$string = implode('_', $exploded);`